# Центр окна на WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Начинаю изучать WPF, после Forms и возникла одна проблема
Центр формы в конструкторе и в запущенной программе отличаются

Форма с шириной 366,6 (из них 6,6 уходит на рамки окна)
Внутри Grid с 1 колонкой и шириной 360
Прямоугольник с шириной 320 и оступом слева 20 - соответственно должен быть в центре, как и видно в конструкторе
Но в программе прямоугольник не по центру, а смещен вправо немного
Даже если выставить ему отступы 0 и HorizontalAlignment="Center"

Такая мелочь, но сижу с ней уже час и бесит жестко)

```
<Window x:Class="Box.Box"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Box"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Box" Height="550" Width="366.4" Background="Black">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="360"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="#00F4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="62" Margin="20,73,20,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="White"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**
Убрал колонку грида и отступы и стало действительно в центре
Но все еще не понятно почему, если задать жестко отступы, но рассчитанные точно под центр, то прямоугольник смещен
Вот пример:
2 прямоугольника, один центрирован через HorizontalAlignment="Center", а второй через HorizontalAlignment="Left" и отступ слева 20
В конструкторе оба по центру, а программе нет

```
<Window x:Class="TokenGames.Box"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TokenGames"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Box" Height="550" Width="366.4" Background="Black">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="#00F4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="White" Margin="20,20,0,0"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="#00F4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="62" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="White" Margin="0,87,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выж сами сделали `Grid` с колонкой, в которую помещаете `Rectangle`. Уберите все отступы, а еще лучше уберите размеры, дайте контролам свободу, пусть сами выбирают что и как им надо. Достаточно просто `HorizontalAlignment` и `VerticalAlignment` Также уберите сетку, ну или `ColumnDefinitions`. Будет вам центр.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. Помогло. Не могли бы вы посмотреть вопрос еще раз. Добавил один момент.

Comment: Если вы таскаете контролы в конструкторе - плохая затея, он вам ставит разные Margin'ы. Изучайте верстку WPF приложений. В вашем случае у обоих прямоугольников разные Margin'ы, обратите внимание (последнее свойство у каждого прямоугольника).

Comment: Мой вам совет, не ориентируйтесь на дизайнер студии, даже советую не пользоваться им, особенно, не передвигать в нем мышью объекты. Дизайнер, это весьма древняя штука, которая не учитывает ряда особенностей, например новых дизайнов OS, как вон в Win11 закругленные углы, другая шапка, и прочее. В итоге, конечное приложение всегда будет другим, чем вы это пишете в дизайнере. У WPF есть "горячая перезагрузка" - это означает то, что вы можете запустить проект под отладкой, и в живую видеть все изменения, которые вы пишете в XAML, вот так вот и проектируйте дизайн.

Comment: И да, кстати, в студии у меня показывает [неровности](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13DLv.png), но это не меняет того, что лучше этим инструментом не пользоваться.